# Laravel failed_jobs connection for different connections

Tags: laravel-queue, laravel-10

Any help would be appreciated.

I need to manage two different connections for laravel Queue jobs.

It's working fine while queueing, But failed_jobs are not working with different connections.

Here is my connection code for queue and failed queues:

```
return [
    'connections' => [
        'database1' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'database' => 'database1',
            'connection' => 'database1',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'database2' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'database' => 'database2',
            'connection' => 'database2',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    'failed' => [
        'database1' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'database' => 'database1',
            'table' => 'failed_jobs',
        ],
        'database2' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'database' => 'database2',
            'table' => 'failed_jobs',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Tried a lot of possibilities, with no success.